# Deny access to specific directory in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am trying to deny public to see files in a special directory using node express following is the code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'partials')));

app.all('/partials/*', function (req,res, next) {

    res.status(403).send(
    {
        message: 'Access Forbidden'
    });
    next();
});
```

If i route to localhost/partials, i get the message 'Access Forbidden' But not if i route to localhost/partials/files.html

Any recommendations?

Comment: what is the role of `options` ?

Comment: actually nothing here...

Comment: i hade some .files that i was trying to hide

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'partials')));` means that all static content in `partials` folder will be accessible by `localhost/files.html`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order of statements matter in `node.js`.

```
app.all('/partials/*', function (req,res, next) {
   res.status(403).send({
      message: 'Access Forbidden'
   });
});

//this line is used to load resources at localhost/partials/api.html
//but, because of above code snippets, we have blocked /partials/* routes
//hence, this line will practically wont work.
app.use('/partials',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'partials')));
```

Comment: @Muskesh Sharma But if i do so i am not able to route to the other pages

Comment: i have partials as a subfolder to public. when i do as u said,  i am not able to route to the other pages. i am also serving public with express.static

Comment: Please not that this will not work if the parent directory of partials is set to be static file directory